# How do I stop random console output in IntelliJ while debugging a flutter app

Tags: flutter, debugging, console

Ever since I upgraded to flutter 3.7 I’ve been having weird printouts occurring in the console when I enter debug mode on iOS and MacOS. Is this related to Xcode and am I able to turn this off?

I’m using an M1 MacBook Pro and IntelliJ for my IDE.

```
Performing hot restart...
Syncing files to device macOS...
Restarted application in 226ms.
1   HIToolbox                           0x000000018f5c85c8 _ZN15MenuBarInstance22EnsureAutoShowObserverEv + 120
2   HIToolbox                           0x000000018f5c8188 _ZN15MenuBarInstance14EnableAutoShowEv + 60
3   HIToolbox                           0x000000018f5358bc _ZN15MenuBarInstance21UpdateAggregateUIModeE21MenuBarAnimationStylehhh + 1184
4   HIToolbox                           0x000000018f5c8004 _ZN15MenuBarInstance19SetFullScreenUIModeEjj + 180
5   AppKit                              0x00000001893b7d30 -[NSApplication _setPresentationOptions:instance:flags:] + 956
6   AppKit                              0x000000018924d93c -[NSApplication _updateFullScreenPresentationOptionsForInstance:] + 404
7   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000185e6a560 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 148
8   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000185f08044 ___CFXRegistrationPost_block_invoke + 88
9   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000185f07f8c _CFXRegistrationPost + 440
10  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000185e3bb64 _CFXNotificationPost + 708
11  Foundation                          0x0000000186d2b38c -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 88
12  AppKit                              0x00000001893b82b4 spacesNotificationHandler + 96
13  SkyLight                            0x000000018aaa5214 _ZN12_GLOBAL__N_123notify_datagram_handlerEj15CGSDatagramTypePvmS1_ + 896
14  SkyLight                            0x000000018add14d4 _ZN21CGSDatagramReadStream26dispatchMainQueueDatagramsEv + 228
15  SkyLight                            0x000000018add13d0 ___ZN21CGSDatagramReadStream15mainQueueWakeupEv_block_invoke + 28
16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000185c0c9dc _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000185c0e504 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000185c1cd1c _dispatch_main_queue_drain + 928
19  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000185c1c96c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 44
20  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000185eb6d40 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 16
21  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000185e747c0 __CFRunLoopRun + 2036
22  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000185e73878 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
23  HIToolbox                           0x000000018f553fa0 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 292
24  HIToolbox                           0x000000018f553de4 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 672
25  HIToolbox                           0x000000018f553b2c _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 72
26  AppKit                              0x00000001890f984c _DPSNextEvent + 632
27  AppKit                              0x00000001890f89dc -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 728
28  AppKit                              0x00000001890ece0c -[NSApplication run] + 464
29  AppKit                              0x00000001890c4250 NSApplicationMain + 880
30  olahina                             0x0000000102baf988 main + 12
31  dyld                                0x0000000185a6be50 start + 2544
```

I've gone into the settings of IntelliJ and Xcode to turn off any options that are related to printing things out on the console but nothing changes.